# There is no implicit reference conversion from 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<double>' to 'System.Collections.IList'

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I am trying to build a method to check if a list is empty:

```
    public static T1 NotEmpty<T1>(T1 argument, string message = null) where T1 : class, IEnumerable
    {
        if (argument == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(message);
        }
        if(!argument.Any())
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(message);
        }
        return argument;
    }
```

and use it like this for instance:

```
public void MyMethod(IList<double> stuff)
{
    _stuff = NotEmpty(stuff);
    ....
}
```

but it doesn't compile. The extension method `Any()` seems to be defined only on the generic version of `IEnumerable`. However, I couldn't define the `NotEmpty` method such that the generic argument implements the generic version of `IEnumerable` and **the compiler is able to work out the types automatically**. The last thing I want is to type all the types manually.

Is it possible to implement it in a more elegant way than the one given below?

```
    public static T1 NotEmpty<T1>(T1 argument, string message = null) where T1 : class, IEnumerable
    {
        if (argument == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(message);
        }
        if(!argument.GetEnumerator().MoveNext())
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(message);
        }
        return argument;
    }
```

Comment: whats wrong with `.Count() == 0` ?

Comment: That's also only implemented on `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: is it? [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357758%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Is this really a problem, though?  If you look at Reflector, the .NET code just does a `foreach` loop over the collection anyway, while checking any predicate that's provided.

Comment: Performance is an issue. Checking if a collection is empty should be `O(1)`

Answer (score 6):

just add an `.OfType<Object>()` to turn your non generic `IEnumerable` into something more useful:

```
public static T1 NotEmpty<T1>(T1 argument, string message = null) where T1 : class, IEnumerable
{
    if (argument == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(message);

    if(!argument.OfType<Object>().Any())
        throw new ArgumentException(message);

    return argument;
}
```

Comment: Note that this will box the items in the sequence if they are value types.

Comment: @servy good point. do you suggest a `.Cast()` instead, as in Tim's answer?

Comment: @Magnus The enumerable objects needs to be a class, not the items that it is enumerating.  Honestly, that constraint makes no sense though.  If it were a value type, it'd be boxed anyway, thus fulfilling the `class` constraint`, so it's really a rather pointless constraint.

Comment: I don't see a real difference here either way.  Honestly, I'd say the OP's code is preferable here, assuming he isn't willing to restrain the argument to `IEnumerable<T>` to begin with.

Answer (score 6):

You could [`Cast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it so that you can use the LINQ extension methods.

`Cast` is an extension method for `IEnumerable`, while most other LINQ extension methods (such as `Any`) are only for `IEnumerable<T>`. Since using `IEnumerable<T>` would complicate your code (due to having two generic types involved), I'd probably go with this:

```
public static T1 NotEmpty<T1>(T1 argument, string message = null) where T1 : class, IEnumerable
{
    if (argument == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(message);
    }
    if(!argument.Cast<object>().Any())
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(message);
    }
    return argument;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why use an Enumerable as generic type? It's about the type of the Enumerable:

```
public static IEnumerable<T1> NotEmpty<T1>(IEnumerable<T1> argument, string message = null) where T1 : class
        {
            if (argument == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(message);
            }
            if(!argument.Any())
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(message);
            }
            return argument;
        }
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, it should've been a comment at best. It's useful to have a generic method such as this `NotEmpty` return *exactly* the same type as what's passed in. `NotEmpty<List<int>>` would have a return type of `List<int>`, not `IEnumerable<int>`.

Comment: @hvd _exactly_ or the _requirement_ to be so is not in stated the question.

Comment: The question already has a correct and working implementation where the return type is that of the argument, and asks for a better (more elegant) implementation of that. Your answer implements something similar but different. That can be okay if it is sufficient for the OP, but in this case, I very much doubt it is.

Comment: @hvd Doesn't need a downvote, it should've been a comment at best (to use your terms)

Comment: Upvoting and downvoting is for when answers are useful or not useful, and currently, I do honestly think that this answer is not useful for this question. Note that that doesn't mean I think the code is not useful at all, just that it's not useful *here*. If the OP edits the question to specify the requirements more precisely and this answer matches those requirements, you'd get an upvote from me.

Comment: @hvd Dying of anticipation... My gratitude for such a noble gesture is tremendous